# Wordpress: Text disappearing on mobile devices

Tags: css, wordpress

I hope someone out there can help.

I am working on this page: http://www.jackjaffa.com/directory/ . The captions for the top 2 guys are disappearing behind the image as soon as you view the page on an iPhone.

I am very fluent with Wordpress and CSS and cannot figure out what I can do to fix this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Need to use media query.
And must read about media query https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Please use this media query css. And let me know any further clarification.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1199px) {
  .department-head-div.executive-div .figure-image, .department-head-div.executive-div .figure-image img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .department .row > div > div{padding-left: 10px;}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .department .row > div > div{
    height: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .department .row > div > div{text-align: center;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The root of your issue is that your images have a set width and height of `250px`, so no matter what size the container is, the image will overflow it, which cuts off the text. If you change:

```
.department-head-div.executive-div .figure-image,
.department-head-div.executive-div .figure-image img {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
}
```

To something along the lines of:

```
.department-head-div.executive-div .figure-image,
.department-head-div.executive-div .figure-image img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 250px;
    height: auto;
}
```

The issue should resolve itself because the images will have a max-width of 250px, but will be constrained by the width of the parent container.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for the following output.

[image]

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .department-head-div.executive-div .row > div {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .department .row > div > div {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        height: auto;
        display: block;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .department-head-div.executive-div .figure-image, .department-head-div.executive-div .figure-image img {
        height: auto;
        margin: 0 auto;
        float: none;
    }
}
```